# Empaty and telepathy not needed

Tags: empathy, telepathy

I have removed empathy, because I do not use any of the clients, which were available there.
I would like to remove telepathy also. However, I use Skype occasionally.
I am curious if I remove telepathy this is going to affect Skype in any way?
Is it save for the rest of the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the dependencies of skype with `apt-cache showpkg skype`.
If `telepathy`isn`t listed there you can remove it.
If something stops working just install it again, no need to save anything.

Comment: It seems that regarding Skype dependencies it is save to remove telepathy, so I did it. Lets hope that the removal will not affect anything else.